# Why use the square transform to reduce left skew?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference

Suppose all the data is positive. Squaring it means that the bigger values in the hump will get multiplied by a bigger number than the smaller values in the tail. Doesn't that just exacerbate the problem?

Numeric example: 10% of the values at 1, 90% of the values at 100. Squaring it makes the skew even bigger.

Comment: Are you comfortable with how taking the *square root* reduces the skewness of distributions of positive values?  The inevitable consequence is that the inverse of this operation--squaring--must increase skewness.

Comment: @badmax Your example *does not make the skew bigger*, it leaves all reasonable measures of skewness unchanged. Consider not two distinct values in your example distribution, but at least three ... if you apply a similar form of reasoning to that used in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107610/what-is-the-reason-the-log-transformation-is-used-with-right-skewed-distribution/107690#107690) (near the middle where it explains the impact of taking logs on distributional shape), you should be able to see what's going on (keeping in mind the ways that the diagram will change)

Comment: By making the bigger numbers relatively bigger than the numbers in the middle of the distribution, you increase the spread of the right tail, bringing it more into balance with the spread of the left tail, which is what skewness is about (well when speaking of skewness relative to symmetry; you can have a highly asymmetric distribution that is not skewed according to the usual metric.)

Answer (score 1):

10% at 1 and 90% at 100 isn't the greatest example of left skew - it's binary.  Let's look at something a bit more typical of this.  For instance, the SAT scores at a very prestigious university would likely be left skew, since there is a ceiling of 800 (on each section).  I found [this site](http://www.prepscholar.com/sat/s/colleges/Harvard-SAT-scores-GPA) which claims the mean is 750, 25%tile  is 700, 75%tile is 800.  So, let's fake some data and find skewness.  R code (stuff after a # is comment, in this case, the result:

```
library(moments)
set.seed(1234)
SAT <- rnorm(1000, mean = 750, sd = 80)
SAT[SAT > 800] <- 800
quantile(SAT, c(.25, .5, .75))   #696, 749, 799
skewness(SAT) #-0.96
SATsq <- SAT^2
skewness(SATsq) #-0.74
```

So, squaring did lessen skew.  Of course, that variable wasn't *that* skew. Let's suppose that there is some university that is usually as selective as Harvard, but waives all requirements for their sports teams (Harvard does NOT do this).  The president of Harsports U. is a sports fanatic.

```
sports <- rnorm(200, mean = 400, sd = 50)
harsports <- c(SAT, sports)
skewness(harsports)  #-1.3
harsportssq <- harsports^2
skewness(harsportssq)  #-1.03
```

Still not that much negative skew. But squaring did reduce it a bit.

EDIT: We can see this, perhaps, with density plots, although I admit they aren't the clearest indication:

```
plot(density(harsports))
lines(density(harsportssq/800), col = 'red')
```

which yields

[image: Density plot]

But to really see it, you can look at the formula for skew and see what squaring would do.

Comment: Still don't get why but can't argue with results.

Comment: Perhaps plotting histograms would help OP visually see the impact. I'm guessing that it works artificially by changing the centre of gravity upwards by massively increasing the high side, but does it make a meaningful difference to the region of highest density?